# iTunes library on NAS, now want to copy music from other iTunes library

Tags: itunes

I have moved my (smallish) iTunes library off the MacBookAir onto a NAS drive. This works fine. Now I want to move songs from my large iTunes library into the new library and just have to one library shared across the two computers

I'm not afraid of the command line, but I wanted the easy way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about library data (play count et cetera); couldn't you just copy the files to the NAS drive and then add them to both libraries?

Have you considered using iTunes Match? It would allow you to have the songs *in the Cloud* and stream (**and** download) them on the MBA while (supposedly) keeping the libraries in sync.